# Websrcaping html <time class=""></time>

Tags: python, datetime, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the date. But I have got just a None.

```
<div class="article-cover">
<div class="article-cover-img">
<img src="https://api.hvg.hu/Img/da658e97-86c0-40f3-acd3-b0a850f32c30/e6f183bb-25a9-468e-ae30-6d98952ffc00.jpg" alt="Will Smith lemondott amerikai filmakadémiai tagságáról" width="800" height="370">
</div>
<div class="article-cover-text">
<div class="article-info byline">
<div class="info">

<time class="article-datetime" datetime="2022-04-02T08:13:00.0000000+02:00">2022. április. 02. 08:13</time>

<time class="lastdate" datetime="2022-04-02T08:16:17.0000000+02:00">2022. április. 02. 08:16</time>
<a href="/kultura" class="uppercase">Kult</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="article-title article-title">
<h1>Will Smith lemondott amerikai filmakadémiai tagságáról</h1>
</div>
</div>
<button class="articlesavebutton bookmark large" data-id="994e8ff1-f28e-4153-9f6c-87283f187af7" data-event-category="Myhvg_article_save" data-event-action="ClickOnLink" data-event-label="Article_save_MTI"></button>
</div>
```

I would like to get back: 2022. április. 02. 08:13

My code is:

```
article_soup = BeautifulSoup(article.content, "html.parser")
d=article_soup.find('time', class\_='article-datetime')
```

Comment: Have you tried `article_soup.select_one('time.article-datatime').text` ?

Comment: and if `article` is coming from `requests.get` - you don't want to use `.content` as that's the raw data - use `.text` instead which'll have encoding handled for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue is a typo `class\_='article-datetime'` and to get the text use simply the `get_text()` method:

```
article_soup.find('time', class_='article-datetime').get_text()
```

or

```
article_soup.find('time', class_='article-datetime').text
```

##### Example

```
html = '''
<div class="article-cover">
<div class="article-cover-img">
<img src="https://api.hvg.hu/Img/da658e97-86c0-40f3-acd3-b0a850f32c30/e6f183bb-25a9-468e-ae30-6d98952ffc00.jpg" alt="Will Smith lemondott amerikai filmakadémiai tagságáról" width="800" height="370">
</div>
<div class="article-cover-text">
<div class="article-info byline">
<div class="info">

<time class="article-datetime" datetime="2022-04-02T08:13:00.0000000+02:00">2022. április. 02. 08:13</time>

<time class="lastdate" datetime="2022-04-02T08:16:17.0000000+02:00">2022. április. 02. 08:16</time>
<a href="/kultura" class="uppercase">Kult</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="article-title article-title">
<h1>Will Smith lemondott amerikai filmakadémiai tagságáról</h1>
</div>
</div>
<button class="articlesavebutton bookmark large" data-id="994e8ff1-f28e-4153-9f6c-87283f187af7" data-event-category="Myhvg_article_save" data-event-action="ClickOnLink" data-event-label="Article_save_MTI"></button>
</div>'''

article_soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

article_soup.find('time', class_='article-datetime').get_text()
```

##### Output

```
2022. április. 02. 08:13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
adate = soup.findAll("time", {"class": "article-datetime"})
print(adate[0].get_text())
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer.